# Uploading (Android Google Drive Api) large number of files to google drive causes google play services to stop

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

I have an app that uploads a large number of files to google drive.  The app uses android google drive api, the uploading is done programmatially, with a number of callbacks from google play services.  Everything seems to work fine:

1. User selects a bunch of files to upload
2. Touch the upload to google drive
3. Uploaded - Can verify by going to drive.google.com

However when the app tries to upload a large number of files, in the region of 1000; google play services stops.

What happens in the app for such a large number of files is:

1. User selects all the data to upload (1000+)
2. The app creates the files locally from the data
3. Once files are created the app starts to communicate with google drive
4. At this point Google play services stops

I've tried debugging and google search yields why google play service might stop under 'normal' circumstances i.e. not what i'm trying.  In any case i have tried checking the version i'm using and it's the latest for the test device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> - Device: Nexus 7 with Kitkat
> - Api: 19 (kitkat)
> - Google play services: latest (i don't have the device in front of me to tell the exact version)

Comment: Not a help, just FYI. I was having a similar issue with listing (querying) large amounts of files (3000+) using GDAA. It would just give me +/-2000 and quit. I don't know if they fixed it, it was about a year ago and I quit GDAA and backed off to the REST Api.  You may try to state your case [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-DriveAndroid) (I gave up).

Comment: @seanpj thanks for that.  I'm not sure if drive api does an implicit query prior to creating the files, but the app doesn't do any querying.  I'd imagine it would, but as drive api doesn't over write the files if duplicates, not sure what an implicit query would accomplish.

Comment: The comment was not specific to your problem. What I meant, is that GDAA is a layer that helps a lot with little things, but anytime I put pressure on it, it came back with some surprises. The worst was latency where I would get a failure in different scenarios, only to get a correct result much later etc. Or a new version of GooPlaySvcs that would pull the rug underneath me. I keep switching between REST and GDAA hoping that one day, I'll get it right.

Comment: Can you attach a stack trace or logcat around the time Google play services stops?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't keep the stack trace, it's been sufficiently frustrating that i've changed the code completely now.  I'm now moved over to using the REST Api, i'll soon find out if that gives me the same issue